# Como ordenar eventos interligados com JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um Sistema Web que possui uma página que pode conter 4 blocos de Script. Eu escrevi um **Script** que pode ser encontrado em um desses blocos, mas não sei qual deles, isso é manipulado pelo Controller.

Inseri alguns eventos **Onclick** em um botão, mas às vezes eles executam em uma **ordem** que eu não esperava.

Existe uma maneira de garantir a **ordem** de execução?

Answer (score 0):

Segue um plugin jQuery que liga um ouvinte de eventos que é acionado sempre antes dos outros:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.bindFirst = function(/*String*/ eventType, /*[Object])*/ eventData, /*Function*/ handler) {
        var indexOfDot = eventType.indexOf(".");
        var eventNameSpace = indexOfDot > 0 ? eventType.substring(indexOfDot) : "";

        eventType = indexOfDot > 0 ? eventType.substring(0, indexOfDot) : eventType;
        handler = handler == undefined ? eventData : handler;
        eventData = typeof eventData == "function" ? {} : eventData;

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var currentAttrListener = this["on" + eventType];

            if (currentAttrListener) {
                $this.bind(eventType, function(e) {
                    return currentAttrListener(e.originalEvent); 
                });

                this["on" + eventType] = null;
            }

            $this.bind(eventType + eventNameSpace, eventData, handler);

            var allEvents = $this.data("events") || $._data($this[0], "events");
            var typeEvents = allEvents[eventType];
            var newEvent = typeEvents.pop();
            typeEvents.unshift(newEvent);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Notas:**

1 - Isso não foi totalmente testado.

2 - Baseia-se no interno da estrutura jQuery não mudando (testado apenas com 1.5.2).

3 - Não será necessariamente desencadeada antes dos ouvintes de eventos que estão vinculados de forma alguma além de um atributo do elemento de origem ou usando jQuery bind() e outras funções associadas.